# Getting query result as CSV in PL/SQL using exactly the same command as in SQL with hint

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, plsql, oracle11g

I am able to get the result as CSV in Oracle by using this simple query with a hint.

```
SELECT /*csv*/ * FROM dual;
```

This returns

```
"DUMMY"
"X"
```

Now I would like to use exactly the same hint in PL/SQL in order not to reinvent the wheel.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
  cur sys_refcursor;
  csv_line varchar2(4000);
begin
  open cur for select /*csv*/ * from dual;
  loop
    fetch cur into csv_line;
    exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line(csv_line);
  end loop;
  close cur;
end;
```

Unfortunately this prints only

```
X
```

which seems to ignore the hint.

Any way to do it that simple or do I have to write a special piece of code for exporting the data as CSV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/*csv*/` hint is [specific to SQL Developer](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/05/formatting-query-results-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer/) and it's sibling SQLCl; and is somewhat superseded by the `set sqlformat csv` option.

It is not a hint recognised by the optimiser; those are denoted by a plus sign, e.g. `/*+ full(...) */` or less commonly `--+ full(...)`.

If you're creating the output in PL/SQL you will need to construct the string yourself, adding the double quotes and delimiters. You can either have the cursor query do that so you can select into a single string even when you have multiple columns; or have a 'normal' query that selects into a record and have PL/SQL add the extra characters around each field as it's output.

It would be more normal to use `utl_file` than `dbms_output` as the client may not have that enabled anyway, but of course that writes to a directory on the server. If you're writing to a file on the client then PL/SQL may not be appropriate or necessary.

If you need to do some manipulation of the data in PL/SQL then one other option is to use a collection type and have an output/bind ref cursor, and then have SQL Developer print that as CSV. But you don't normally want to be too tied to a single client.

Comment: Pity. Thanks for the answer though! I think I will go with `UTL_FILE`.